# About the determinant of a $4\times 4$ Vandermonde matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

I'm struggling with proving the Vandermonde matrix of dimension 4x4.
I don't want to get into induction, if that is possible.
I know there is a lot of material on the internet but I am looking for a calculation solution, and not an induction one.
I have reached this expression:

$$
a_1^3(a_4-a_3)(a_3-a_2)(a_4-a_2)-a_2^3(a_4-a_3)(a_4-a_1)(a_3-a_1)+a_3^3(a_4-a_2)(a_4-a_1)(a_2-a_1)-a_4^3(a_3-a_2)(a_3-a_1)(a_2-a_1)
$$
Obviously this is a very long expression to simplify.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest using subscripts: $a1^3$ becomes $a_1^3$ by using `a_1^3`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, didnt know how to do that. Edited.

Comment: You're welcome, hrsidkpi

Comment: I don't know what is your present level of study, but if  I have an advise to give : "don't loose too much time on such things". Seeing this as a drill for algebraic hand calculation, why not ? But, there are more profitable exercices. In particular, human beings are not able at all in performing complicated factorizations, as is the case here, whereas CAS (Computer Algebra Systems) are very good at that. Leave to Caesar....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let we consider the following problem: to find a third-degree polynomial $p(x)=c_3 x^3+c_2 x^2 + c_1 x + c_0$ that equals $1$ at $x=a_1$ and $0$ at $x=a_i$ with $i\neq 1$.
By Lagrange interpolation we know that the solution is given by
$$ p(x) = \frac{(x-a_2)(x-a_3)(x-a_4)}{(a_1-a_2)(a_1-a_3)(a_1-a_4)} \tag{1}$$
so, for instance,
$$ c_0 = p(0) = \frac{-a_2 a_3 a_4}{(a_1-a_2)(a_1-a_3)(a_1-a_4)}.\tag{2} $$
On the other hand, the problem can be stated in the following way: find $(c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3)\in\mathbb{R}^4$ such that
$$ \begin{pmatrix}1 & a_1 & a_1^2 & a_1^3 \\ 1 & a_2 & a_2^2 & a_2^3 \\ 1 & a_3 & a_3^2 & a_3^3 \\ 1 & a_4 & a_4^2 & a_4^3 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}c_0\\ c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\tag{3} $$
If we solve such problem through [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) we find:
$$ c_0 = \frac{\det \begin{pmatrix}a_2 & a_2^2 & a_2^3 \\  a_3 & a_3^2 & a_3^3 \\ a_4 & a_4^2 & a_4^3 \end{pmatrix}}{\det \begin{pmatrix}1 & a_1 & a_1^2 & a_1^3 \\ 1 & a_2 & a_2^2 & a_2^3 \\ 1 & a_3 & a_3^2 & a_3^3 \\ 1 & a_4 & a_4^2 & a_4^3 \end{pmatrix}}=a_2 a_3 a_4\cdot \frac{\det \begin{pmatrix}1 & a_2 & a_2^2 \\  1 & a_3 & a_3^2 \\ 1 & a_4 & a_4^2 \end{pmatrix}}{\det \begin{pmatrix}1 & a_1 & a_1^2 & a_1^3 \\ 1 & a_2 & a_2^2 & a_2^3 \\ 1 & a_3 & a_3^2 & a_3^3 \\ 1 & a_4 & a_4^2 & a_4^3 \end{pmatrix}}\tag{4}$$
and to prove the claim it is enough to compare $(2)$ and $(4)$, given:
$$ \det \begin{pmatrix}1 & a_2 & a_2^2 \\  1 & a_3 & a_3^2 \\ 1 & a_4 & a_4^2 \end{pmatrix}=\det \begin{pmatrix}1 & a_2 & a_2^2 \\  0 & a_3-a_2 & a_3^2-a_2^2 \\ 0 & a_4-a_2 & a_4^2-a_2^2 \end{pmatrix}\\=(a_3-a_2)(a_4-a_2)\det\begin{pmatrix}1 & a_3+a_2 \\ 1 & a_4 + a_2\end{pmatrix}=(a_3-a_2)(a_4-a_2)(a_4-a_3).\tag{5} $$
As an alternative, you may directly use Gaussian elimination as performed in $(5)$ to tackle the original problem with a $4\times 4$ Vandermonde matrix.

But out  of curiosity, what is the purpose of avoiding induction?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to prove the *general* formula, with some simple results on polynomials in several indeterminates. Consiider the Vandermonde determinant:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&\dots&1\\
a_1&a_2&\dots&a_n\\
a_1^2&a_2^2&\dots&a_n^2\\
\vdots&&&\vdots\\
a_1^{n-1}&a_2^{n-1}&\dots&a_n^{n-1}
\end{vmatrix}$$
The general formula for the determinant: 
$$\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}(-1)^{\varepsilon(\sigma)}c_{1\,\sigma(1)}c_{2\,\sigma(2)}\dotsm c_{n\,\sigma(n)}=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}(-1)^{\varepsilon(\sigma)}1\cdot a_{\sigma(2)}\dotsm a_{\sigma(n)}^{n-1}$$
shows this determinant is *homogeneous* in the indeterminates $a_1, a_2, \dots,a_n$, with degree
$$1+2+\dots+(n-1)=\frac{n(n-1)}2.$$
Now *Vandermonde* determinant is $0$ whenever $a_i=a_j$ for some $1\le i <j .\le n$. Hence it is divisible by $a_j-a_i$. As these polynomials are pairwise coprime, *Gauß's lemma* ensures it is divisible by their product
$$(a_2-a_1)\dotsm(a_n-a_1)(a_3-a_2)\dotsm (a_n-a_2)\dotsm(a_n-a_{n-1}).$$
Observe this product has precisely degree $\dfrac{n(n-1)}2$. Hence it is a constant × the determinant. Considering the term $a_1^{n-1}a_2^{n-2}\dotsm a_{n-1}$ in the expansion of the general formula, we see this coefficient is $1$.